# Delimiter for Python-3.x regex pattern

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Is there a way to set a delimiter to a Python 3.x regex pattern so that you can set the flags to it, without having to use re.compile?

Here is a code example:

```
pattern = r'%[aeiou]{1}%mi'
return re.findall(pattern, string)
```

The `mi` stands for multiline and case insensitive and `%` is the delimiter in my case.

I remember python 2.5 having this option of setting the delimiters of the pattern string as I used them once.

Comment: you mean this `r'(?mi)[aeiou]{1}'` ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj i remember having the option of setting a delimiter such as % or # and the putting those flags in the back, which were valid for the whole pattern.

Comment: that's php not python..

Comment: I'm sure your last but one comment wasn't like that a few minutes ago. Removed. @AvinashRaj